# A hook that would check if the module is enable?

Tags: 7, hooks

**I'm not looking for hook_enable (which would trigger when the module is been enable).**

I have a module that would work alone (lets call it custom_module_1) and I have another module which is an add-on (lets call it custom_module_2) to that module to the custom_module_1. I want to be able to have a different behavior on the custom_module_1 if the custom_module_2 is enable.

So I'm looking for a hook that would be be using on custom_module_1 and would check if the custom_module_2 is enable.

Or how can I check if there is a module enable as a function to have a different behavior on another module ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`module_exists($module)` will do that for you.  From [the API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_exists/7):

> Parameters
>
> string $module: The name of the module (without the .module extension).
>
> Return value
>
> bool TRUE if the module is both installed and enabled, FALSE otherwise.